# TreeView and Entity Framework binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to WPF and EF; I've looked but I wasn't able to find appropriate help.

---

This is what I have:

**Entity Framework** (*ReportDefinition.ParentID* and *ReportDefinition.SectionID* are *Section.idSections*), **ReportDefinition example** and **Section example**.

This is what I would like to present:

**TreeView**.

[image: Diagram Picture].

---

I'm trying to achieve this programmatically. I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a collection of top-level `ReportDefinition` objects:

```
TopLevelReportDefinitions = ReportDefinitions.Where(rd => rd.ParentID == 0)
```

You need to bind this collection to the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView`.

In EF, you also need to create a parent-child relation on `ReportDefinition` linking the children to the parent using `ParentID`. For convenience you can name the reverse collection `Children`. The collection of `ReportDefinition` objects directly below another `ReportDefinition` is then the collection:

```
ReportDefinition.Children
```

You then have to create `HierarchicalTemplate` in the `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelReportDefinitions}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Martin. This is what I did:  `using (var context = new reportEntities(entityConnectionString))  {  var TopLevelReportDefinitions = context.ReportDefinitions.Where(rd => rd.ParentID == 0);  tvReport.ItemsSource = TopLevelReportDefinitions.ToList();  }`  I've also added the suggested template to the TreeView. Unfortunately I'm not able to figure out how to create the parent-child relation. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @Yeseanul: One option is to create the relation in the database (a foreign key from ParentID to idReportDefinition). Then, if you update your model from the database, I would expect EF to create properties for the relation in the model. The names will not be `Parent` and `Children` but you can rename them.

Comment: I've did just that (added a foreign key in the database and updated the model) but to no success. I ended up extending the `public partial class ReportDefinition : EntityObject` that EF created; so I've added a property `public IList<Section> GetChildren`. I've also changed the template accordingly `<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding GetChildren}">`. This approach does provide some results: the TreeView shows only the Children BUT doesn't show the Parents. Another problem is that this doesn't show Grand-Children, Grand-Grand-Children... Any thoughts on this?

Comment: OK, problem solved. What I did is added two properties to the class created by EF `public partial class ReportDefinition : EntityObject`: `public IList<ReportDefinition> Children` and `public string Name`. This works with the XML provided in the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yeseanul, do you mind adding to your initial question with the info on how you created these additional properties? I am stuck in a very similar situation (and am wondering if this is an alternative to me creating a collection of anonymous type (which I just learned today)). Thank you kindly :)

Comment: @UB3571 The `public partial class ReportDefinition : EntityObject` is generated by EF. Being a partial class, you can extend it. Therefore, in you code, just declare a `public partial class ReportDefinition` and add to it whatever you want/need. In my case, it was the two above-mentioned properties (I added much more that that, but those two helped resolve the issue that I had).

Comment: Thank you. The little extra clarification helped. :)