# Entity framework and treeview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, treeview

I have a RDB and three tables inside the database. The first table is animal, second table is Breed and third table is Name.

The ER diagram among the tables is:

Name - Animal (many to one)

Breed - Animal (many to one)

Name - Breed (many to one)

I would like to do programatically the treeview. However I wonder how to do it using entities framework. The closest Idea I found was...[TreeView and Entity Framework binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481799/treeview-and-entity-framework-binding)...but the threeview must simply show animal as parent, breed as child and Name as child from breed, without using table values to represent the level in the treeview like in the example. I guess, it is a way to organize which table is the parent and which is the child. isn´t it?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve soved it by using SQL and foreign keys.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT `{2}`, `{1}` FROM `{0}` WHERE `{3}`=" + tb_child_key, childTable, childColumn, id_column, index.ToString()), con);
```